# What should I use on linux > 2.6.28 instead of __arch__swab32

Tags: linux-kernel, powerpc

I keep getting compilation error for a kernel module:

```
XXX: In function 'yyy':
ZZZ:125: error: implicit declaration of function '__arch__swab32'
```

PowerPC, 2.6.30.x, Kamikaze toolchain. According to [this](http://lxr.kelp.or.kr/ident?a=ppc;i=__arch__swab32) the identifier went away after 2.6.28. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the generic `__swab32` from `linux/swab.h` (which also exists on earlier kernel versions).